# Bootstrap Multiple Collapse items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using the standard bootstrap collapse tool:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But i need more than 3 collapse items and when I copy and paste another set of the same 3 collapse items, instead of working independently each item # opens and closes simultaneously. Any idea how that can be fixed since I don't want anyone of them to be related with the other.

Thanks!

Comment: did you added different *ID* to each collapse items? also check for the parents

Comment: How did you copy paste them? Please share your final output for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure every div you want to collapse has different ID and data-target attribute of a appropriate button is the same as the ID of a div.

like this:

```
<button data-target="#collapseTwo"> 
<div id="collapseTwo">

<button data-target="#collapseThree"> 
<div id="collapseThree">

<button data-target="#collapseFour"> 
<div id="collapseFour">
```

and so on. I hope this was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Make user you use new ID for these elements each time you copy and paste. :)

Please check my comments on this code.

**newBtnId** should be equal in 2 places. Please check the code carefully!

```
enter code here
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="newHeading">
    <!-- newHeading is a new id  -->
     <h2 class="mb-0">
    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#NewBtnId" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
    <!-- newBtnId is a new id  -->
      Collapsible Group Item #4
    </button>
  </h2>
</div>
<div id="newBtnId" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
  <!-- newBtnId is a new id  -->
  <div class="card-body">
   
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="newHeading">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#newBtnId " aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #4
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="newBtnId" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to make it work independently you should change the "id","data-target" and "aria-controls" to a unique name.
i have changed these items, copy this to add more 3 collapse items ...

```
   <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                </button>
            </h2>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data- parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
                wolf moon
                officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                Brunch 3 wolf
                moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
                Nihil anim
                keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan
                excepteur
                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
                you probably
                haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
                    Collapsible Group Item #2
                </button>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
                wolf moon
                officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                Brunch 3 wolf
                moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
                Nihil anim
                keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan
                excepteur
                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
                you probably
                haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
            <h2 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSix"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix">
                    Collapsible Group Item #3
                </button>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3
                wolf moon
                officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                Brunch 3 wolf
                moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et.
                Nihil anim
                keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan
                excepteur
                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt
                you probably
                haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```